# NetLogo: correct while and ifelse conditions?

Tags: netlogo

I have a troubles to logically organize my **while** and **ifelse** conditions in NetLogo.

I have a target money which I need to spend within a year (1 tick). Also, I have target timber value, which I need to harvest within this year. Thus, 3 possibilities can emerge:

- 1: I have enough money to meet my timber goals
- 2: I have more money
  that I need to spend to meet my harvest goals - I save money - `money saved, timber meet`
- 3: I
  have less money that I need to meet my harvest goals - I
  can not harvest enough  `money spent, timber not meet`

However, my while loop doesn't work as expected, i.e. when I correctly spend my moneys and meet timber golas, for some reason I get to condition to "`money spent, timber not meet`", which is not true.

Please, can you see in my **while** and **ifelse** conditions how can I arrange them to have as an output my 3 expected outputs? Or how can I write a code better?

Thank you !

The while and ifelse loop:

```
 while [ real_money_year >= 0  ] [  ;and real_timber_year <= timber_target_year
      ifelse real_money_year > 0    ; continue if you have enough money
        [
          ifelse real_timber_year < timber_target_year ; is your timber goal meet?
             [  ; timber goal is not meet and DR have enough money to harvest
               move-to one-of patches with [patch_timb_stock > 0]
               pen-down ; see the path
               set real_timber_year patch_timb_stock + real_timber_year   ; increase timber gain after each harvest  
               set real_money_year real_money_year - patch_harvest_cost   ; decrease money after each harvest
               set pcolor magenta
               print "harvest"
              ]
             [;timber value is meet, however we have more money to spend
               print "money saved, timber meet"
               stop
             ]
        ]
        [ ; there is not enough money to meet timber goals
          print "money spent, timber not meet"
          stop
        ]
    ]
```

---

Whole code:

```
globals [


  ;timber_target_year       ; what is defined timber target per year?
  ;money_target_year        ; how much money do I have to spend per year

  ; values that DR is able to spend within a year
  real_timber_year         ; how much do I really harvest in one year
  real_money_year          ; how much money did I really spend  in one year?
]

patches-own [
  patch_harvest_cost   ; what is the cost of harvest of specific patch?
  patch_timb_stock     ; what is the timber stack of the patch?
]

to setup
  clear-all
  setup-rangers    ; create DR
  setup-patches    ; create forest 
  reset-ticks
end

to setup-rangers
  crt 1 [
    set color red ]
end  ; setup ranger

to setup-patches
  ask patches [
    set pcolor green
    set patch_harvest_cost p_harvest_cost
    set patch_timb_stock p_timber_stock
  ]
   set real_money_year money_target_year
end ; setup patches


to go
  ask turtles [
    harvest
  ]
  tick
end




to harvest

    while [ real_money_year >= 0  ] [  ;and real_timber_year <= timber_target_year
      ifelse real_money_year > 0    ; continue if you have enough money
        [
          ifelse real_timber_year < timber_target_year ; is your timber goal meet?
             [  ; timber goal is not meet and DR have enough money to harvest
               move-to one-of patches with [patch_timb_stock > 0]
               pen-down ; see the path
               set real_timber_year patch_timb_stock + real_timber_year   ; increase timber gain after each harvest  
               set real_money_year real_money_year - patch_harvest_cost   ; decrease money after each harvest
               set pcolor magenta
               print "harvest"
              ]
             [;timber value is meet, however we have more money to spend
               print "money saved, timber meet"
               stop
             ]
        ]
        [ ; there is not enough money to meet timber goals
          print "money spent, timber not meet"
          stop
        ]
    ] 

end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should only be able to reach that condition if `real_money_year = 0`, so test for that.  More to the point, you seem to want a logic more like:

```
while [(real_money_year > 0)  and (real_timber_year < timber_target_year)] [
  move-to one-of patches with [patch_timb_stock > 0]  ;NOTE: assumes such a patch exists!
  set real_money_year real_money_year - patch_harvest_cost
  set real_timber_year (patch_timb_stock + real_timber_year)
]
ifelse (real_timber_year >= timber_target_year) [
  print (word "timber goal met, money saved = " real_money_year)  ;possibly 0
][
  print "money spent, timber goal not met"
]
```

Comment: Cool, thank you @Alan, it works ! :) yes, I think that I've overcomplicated it ....  I am surprized that the `ifelse` is not included in `while`. Why it is?